# Check multiple div's data- attributes and return only those that exist to a separate list

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

here's the question that I have:

The HTML structure is following:

```
<div class="a-pin" data-alpha=2>City One</div>
<div class="a-pin" data-alpha=3 data-beta=1>City Two</div>
<div class="a-pin" data-beta=2 data-gamma=8>City Three</div>
```

There can be any number of similar `divs` with different but similar `data` attributes. Somehow, with the help of jQuery I need to check `data-` attributes of selected `div` and `return`(!) a list of EACH `data-` attribute and its value in a popup that should look like this (for the second div in example):

Total projects:
Alpha stuff: 3
Beta stuff: 1

Don't worry about the popup, it's already in the code and should go like this:

```
popupText.html( 'Total projects: <br>' + the-list-that-I-need );
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Please show the desired output. Right now it's not really clear what the grouping function is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by retrieving all the `data` attributes on the elements by using `data()`. You can then loop over these to generate the required HTML. Try this:

```
$('.a-pin').click(function() {
    var data = $(this).data();
    var output = '';
    for (var key in data)
        output += key + ': ' + data[key] + '<br />';
    $('#output span').html(output);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/50qy80gd/)

Comment: Thank you @rory-mccrossan, it works like expected, the only thing is that now it output raw `data key`, so final output is like this `'alpha: 3'`. How can I replace it with my custom line like `'My Alpha stuff: 3'`? I tried to replace each `key` with what I want but then `data[key]` doesn't work obviously because the key is changed...

Comment: If I've understood what you mean, you just need to change this line: `output += 'My ' + key + ' stuff: ' + data[key] + '<br />';` http://jsfiddle.net/50qy80gd/1/

Comment: Well not exactly, I have to have ability to completely change the name. Already done it by using .replace method.

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla version, maybe it's helpful.

```
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.a-pin')),
    gatherAttributes = function ( node ) {
        return Array.prototype.slice.call(node.attributes).reduce(function ( acc, att ) {
            var name = att.name;
            if (/data.+/.test(name)) acc[name] = node.getAttribute(name);
            return acc;
        }, {});
    };
nodes.forEach(function ( node ) {
    var result = gatherAttributes(node);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```